# Joomla 1.5 - Displaying an content in a modal popup?

Tags: joomla

I would like to place a link to an article that contains some HTML and have that appear in a modal popup.
Modal pop-ups are maybe not already enabled on my web site. How I can enable them?

**SOLVED:**

Many JOOMLA templates turn the modal behavior ON. If not add this to main index `<head></head>`

```
<?php JHTML::_('behavior.modal'); ?>
```

On an article (HTML editor) use class="modal". Format your link like:

```
<a class="modal" href="terms/tou.html" rel="{handler:'iframe',size:{x:700,y:600}}">TOU</a>
```

Comment: have you tried anything of your own, be that code or a 3rd party extension?

Comment: @Lodder SqueezeBox - Expandable Lightbox